# How to exclude rendering existing script in DOM in Yii2

Tags: yii2

How to exclude in rendering already existing scripts in DOM in Yii2

What method (render or renderAjax etc.) i have to use to exclude rendering one more (the same) jquery, jquery.ui

I have jquery.js on my page. And i (via ajax) load to my page modal window of registration, that requires jquery.js, and it pulls jquery.js second time.

And in the result my page contains 2 jquery.js library. And somewhere starts ocurring errors. I want to fix it by remoeving enother jquery.js

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Bizley , I have `jquery.js` on my page. And i (via ajax) load to my page modal window of registration, that requires `jquery.js`, and it pulls `jquery.js` second time. And in the result my page contains 2 `jquery.js` library. And somewhere starts ocurring errors. I want to fix it by remoeving enother `jquery.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using AssetBundle class but if not - you should.

There is already defined `yii\web\JqueryAsset` with jquery.js you can use.
Now you can create AssetBundle with your script that will depend on JqueryAsset (read more about assets dependency in the [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#asset-dependencies)). No matter how many times this asset is registered JqueryAsset will be registered only once.

You can do the same when adding single js file with [registerJsFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile()-detail) - in options array you can use `'depends'` key with the JqueryAsset.

Comment: you misunderstand me. I already using `yii\web\JqueryAsset`. But what i have now - i got already loaded with js and css web page in my browser. And after it i load via ajax my another page that pulls another one `jquery.js`. So how i can to prevent pasting `jquery.js` into DOM when i already have `jquery.js`

Comment: Is there any reason why you pull **whole** page via ajax instead just a part of it you need?

Comment: I don't know how to pull just a part of what i need. But i found a solution. http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-resource-smart-load/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry again. I found solution. [Here is it](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-resource-smart-load/)